# Real Analysis - continuity of the function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I do not know how to solve below problem using Continuity definition.

Prove that $f(x)=x^n$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ for any positive integer $n$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Which continuity definition are you using?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the identity $$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+ \dots+x y^{n-2}+y^{n-1}). $$